# Trying to update with a case scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update with SQL using a case. My goal is to update field3 in my tabel with field1 if that field has a number. but if it does not have a number then I want to update field3 with field2. When I use my code I get the following error.

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 11. Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.

This is my code:

```
Update [dbo].[oracle_reconciliation_report$]
SET [Forecast] =
    (
      Select [Forecast],
           [ProposedApprovedCapitalExpenditureForecast ],
           [ProposedCIP CapitalExpenditureForecast],
      case when [ProposedApprovedCapitalExpenditureForecast ] > 0 
         then [ProposedApprovedCapitalExpenditureForecast ]
      else [ProposedCIP CapitalExpenditureForecast] 
      end
    )
From [dbo].[oracle_reconciliation_report$]
```

I am trying to update field3 in my tabel with field1 if that field has a number, but if it does not have a number then I want to update field3 with field2

Comment: in your question please add tag for the database engine you're using

Comment: You have 3 columns in your subquery but are trying to assign it to one column. That doesn't work. If you referred to the actual column names in the query rather than "field1", "field2, "field3" in your description, it might be possible to give you an answer with a query that does what you want.

Comment: When you used the SQL tag, a large message was shown to you that suggested that you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax varies between them. Why did you ignore that suggestion? You've simply made it take longer for you to get an answer, as well as possibly wasting the time of people who go ahead and try to help by answering only to find out it won't work for your DBMS. When this site (or someone on it) gives you advice, it's in your best interest to **take it**.

Comment: The inner select must be a "scalar subquery". This means it must return a SINGLE value, not FOUR.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logic, I would expect logic like this:

```
Update [dbo].[oracle_reconciliation_report$]
    set Forecast = (case when [ProposedApprovedCapitalExpenditureForecast ] > 0 
                         then [ProposedApprovedCapitalExpenditureForecast ] > 0 
                         else [ProposedCIP CapitalExpenditureForecast]
                    end)
    From [dbo].[oracle_reconciliation_report$];
```

Perhaps this will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks that worked, apologies for everyone not tagging properly. I probably am too new to post because I tried to delete the question when I realized I had tagged wrong or at least update the tags but I couldn't figure that out. Thank you Gordon Linoff for your help.